# Using htaccess to remove trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slash, trailing

I have a url "www.example.com/abc/abc.php"
If I change it to "www.example.com/abc/abc.php/asdasd", some kind of infinite loop starts and the server's memory peaks to 100%.

I have heard that there's some way by .htaccess by which I can redirect any "abc.php/asdasd" to "abc.php" only. Please help how, as I am not able to understand it from other examples mentioned on net.

NOTE : I dont want this "/" to be removed if it is put at the end of directories though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by the following htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php/(.*) $1.php [F]
</IfModule>
```

This may not be perfect, but gets the job done. Now anything after the text 'abc.php' results in a page-not-found.
Works for cases like :

www.website.com/abc.php/

www.website.com/abc.php/asd

www.website.com/abc.phpasd

www.website.com/abc.php?

etc.

Comment: Since your .htaccess script gives a 404 error for `www.website.com/abc.php?`, it could be a problem if you ever want to [use Google Analytics URL builder](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) for custom campaigns

Answer (score 2):

This would redirect one URL to another:

```
Redirect 301 /abc.php/adssd http://www.example.com/abc.php
```

However, this will only handle this one example. You should post your full .htaccess file so we can see what's really going on

Comment: I dont have an htaccess yet. I want all the files in my server that end with a ".php" to stay that way even after adding a "/" or "/abcd" after php .

Comment: You can read this for more detailed info. http://serverfault.com/questions/175517/apache-htaccess-remove-everything-after-php However, I wouldn't recommend this. You shouldn't be in an infinite loop when you enter a random URL. You should look at your code and see if there is another problem going on